# Is there a way to printf five elements of an array per row?

Tags: arrays, c

I have the code below. I am attempting to printf the elements in the array in the following manner:

40  20  90  90  80
70  61  60  50  40
20  10  61  70  30
90  70  80  40  50
100  59

The elements that are being entered are as follows:
40 20 90 90 80 70 61 60 50 40 20 10 61 70 30 90 70 80 40 50 100 59 -1

```
    int main()
{
    int  i, n, ScoresFromTest[SIZE] ;
    printf("Number of scores: ") ;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the numbers:\n") ;
    for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        scanf("%d", &ScoresFromTest[i]);
    int size = n;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(ScoresFromTest[i] != -1)
            printf("%3d", ScoresFromTest[i]);
        if((i > 0) && (i % 5 == 0))
            printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    sort(ScoresFromTest, size);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(ScoresFromTest[i] != -1)
            printf("%3d", ScoresFromTest[i]);
        if((i > 0) && (i % 5 == 0))
            printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    printf("score    frequency\n");
    printf("-----    ---------\n");

   frequency(ScoresFromTest, size);
   printf("Passing:  %.2f%% \n", pPercent(ScoresFromTest, size));
    printf("\n");
   printf("Failing:  %.2f%% \n", fPercent(ScoresFromTest, size));
    printf("\n");
   printf("Mean:     %.2f\n", mean(ScoresFromTest, size));
    printf("\n");
   printf("Mode:     %d\n", mode(ScoresFromTest, size));
    printf("\n");
   printf("Median:   %.2f\n", median(ScoresFromTest, size));
    printf("\n");
    
}
```

Comment: So print a newline every 5 scores. `if ((i > 0) && (i % 5 == 0)) printf("\n")`. You'll have to adjust that for skipping invalid scores.

Comment: What is the definition of `SIZE`?

Comment: I've added the if ((i > 0) && (i % 5 == 0)) printf("\n"), but its not working. hmmm...

Comment: @kaylum, please, write an answer, as in my opinion, Josh doesn't know where to put the line of code you have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have been suggested (in the comments) to include a line

```
if ((i > 0) && (i % 5 == 0))
    printf("\n");
```

and you included in the correct place:

```
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(ScoresFromTest[i] != -1)
            printf("%3d", ScoresFromTest[i]);
        if((i > 0) && (i % 5 == 0))
            printf("\n");
```

but you forgot to group the two statements, so the second `if` statement (the one you just included) **is not part of the loop** (even if you indented it to be at the same level as the other `if` statement, C is not python)  They should be grouped together using brackets:

```
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { /* you need to group statements to include
them in the loop */
        if(ScoresFromTest[i] != -1)
            printf("%3d", ScoresFromTest[i]);
        if((i > 0) && (i % 5 == 0))
            printf("\n");
    }
```

This will make the `if` to be executed *inside the loop*, and not at the end (when it is not necessary anymore)

## Note

Please, next time, visit [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post your code according to the Stackoverflow rules, or your code will not be able to be tested and we'll not be able to help you.  To test your code (which is not minimal) I'd need to provide code for `sort`, `frequency`, `pPercent`, `mean`, `mode` and `median` functions, for which you don't provide even correct prototypes, and this is far more than necessary to be able to test your code.

Finally, your code couldn't be tested without providing all those functions, so the code you included couldn't be tested at all.